# Summarising all fields in attribute table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcmap

I was hoping to run a script that will iterate through all fields in an attribute table, SUM each field and produce the result in a table.

The script below will essentially do what I want with one field but is there a way for it to iterate through all fields?

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import env  

env.workspace = "C:/data/Habitat_Analysis.gdb"  

arcpy.Statistics_analysis("FIELD_NAME", "C:/output/output.gdb/TABLE_OUTPUT", [["SUM"]])
```

(the above sample was sourced here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000)

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't the third example script in the link you mentioned do exactly what you want in a single table?

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:/data/Habitat_Analysis.gdb"

# Set local variables
intable = "FIELD_NAME"
outtable = "C:/output/output.gdb/TABLE_OUTPUT"
# casefield = "Name" Not used
stats = []

# Loop through all fields in the Input Table
for field in arcpy.ListFields(intable):
    # Just find the fields that have a numeric type
    if field.type in ("Double", "Integer", "Single", "SmallInteger"):
        # Add the field name and Sum statistic type
        #    to the list of fields to summarize
        stats.append([field.name, "Sum"])
# Correct formatting of stats [["Field1", "Sum"], ["Field2", "Sum"], ...]

# Run the Summary Statistics tool with the stats list
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(intable, outtable, stats)
```

Comment: That's exactly how I would do it except inTable and outTable would be arguments to make that more flexible... and I'd also skip the OIDFieldName http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000003m000000 as the sum of that is (likely) of no value

Comment: The OID field is type OID, not Double, Integer, Single, or SmallInteger, so it's sum won't be in the output.  See the type property under the arcpy field class.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000004n000000

Comment: Sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't, just to be sure I exclude it specifically. In reality it's just a number (INT) that's auto-managed by the database, guaranteed to be unique but not guaranteed to be the same feature every time (shapefile FID's change in an edit session).

Comment: In the case of the code above the listFields for loop with the field.type conditional statement as written will never include the OID field in the output, whether it is a shapefile, dbase table, geodatabase, etc.  You would have to demonstrate a situation where that loop includes an actual OID field sum.

Comment: Not in python using the field.type Richard, that is correct. I script/program in many languages using several API's; trying to remember which ones exclude ID as NUMERIC and which ones don't (including which versions...) can be a little tedious so I just do it anyway. You are absolutely correct, the OID/FID/ID will not be included in your method as the field.type will return "OID" not "Integer", I also like the use of *in* instead of multiple == statements. It got my vote!

Comment: Got it.  I can see why switching to different script/program languages would lead to a better safe than sorry approach.  I just wanted it to be clear that for arcpy using the field type in this way is reliable for excluding the OID.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a SearchCursor wrapped in a generator to get the summed fields.  This is the full workflow:

1. List all of the fields
2. Create a function with a SearchCursor wrapped in a generator
3. Loop through the fields
4. Limit the fields to only those that are necessary with logic and
   implement the function

---

```
import arcpy, os

fc = r'C:\Users\OWNER\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\utm15\mypolys'

fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)

def sumFields(x, y):
    field = sum([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(x, y)])
    print "The sum of Field: %s = %s" % (y, field)

for f in fields:
    if f.type != "OID" and f.type != "Geometry":
        sumFields(fc, f.name)
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does this code respond to a text or date field?

Comment: @RichardFairhurst You are correct that date and text fields should also be controlled for.  Borrowing from your script, something along the lines of the following will work: `if f.type not in ("OID", "Geometry", "Date", "Text"):`

Answer (score 1):

Before you can complete your script I think you should write a short test script that simply takes a feature class and prints out the name of each field using [ListFields](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q30000001t000000).

From there modify your script so that only the names of numeric fields are printed - because you want to SUM them.

The final step is to incorporate a `for` loop to iterate your Summary Statistics.

Comment: Beat me by 6 minutes...

Comment: @Fezter but your answer is more comprehensive

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Your answer appears essentially the same as Fezter but I expanded on his somewhat more.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **[ListFields](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000012000000)** function.  Note, you'll want to limit your results to numeric only fields, otherwise, you might get an error.  So, you may want to use something like the following:

```
int_fields = arcpy.ListFields("C:/data/Habitat_Analysis.gdb", , "Integer")
```

to get a list of all integer fields.

then

```
small_int_fields = arcpy.ListFields("C:/data/Habitat_Analysis.gdb", , "SmallInteger")
```

to get a list of all small integer fields.  Repeat again for doubles.

```
double_fields = arcpy.ListFields("C:/data/Habitat_Analysis.gdb", , "Double")
```

Finally, you can merge the lists together:

```
fields = int_fields + small_int_fields + double_fields
```

Then, you can iterate through all fields with a **[for loop](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)**.

Comment: Hi Fezter, you're onto something there but I would list all fields and use field.type http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000004n000000 to skip over the TEXT, BLOB, GUID... adding to a list as I go. Less typing that way.